Can one build an east-west compass using bismuth?
I am reading Oliver Sacks's memoir Uncle Tungsten, The book is remarkably interesting: he was a keen amateur chemist in his youth, and clearly a polymath.I was struck by this:
"It was fascinating to see how a thin shard of bismuth (as near a needle as I could get with the brittle metal) aligned itself, almost violently, perpendicular with the magnetic field. I wondered whether, if it were sufficiently delicately poised, one might make a bismuth compass that pointed east-west."
So, can one make such a compass? I admit I'm not sure what use it would be, although it might interest the World-builders.

So is "Oliver Sacks's Uncle Tungsten" a work of fiction?

It is a memoir. He was a keen amateur chemist in his youth.

Are you leaving looking for magnetic properties of materials other than iron? Rare earth magnets are stronger than just iron...

I read that book (very good, recommended) but I don't remember anything about bismuth.  I am not sure how to reconcile "aligned itself, almost violently" with the calculations in the answer.  I'll have to dig out the book again.

@user1683793 Gradients near a modern permanent magnet can easily be  10 T/m, compared to roughly 10 pT/m for the Earth's field. Since the settling time depends on the square of the gradient, the settling time could easily be "violently" instantaneous for a bismuth needle levitated by a perimanent magnet.

Well, now I'm confused: is the settling time '∼100,000 years' or is it 'the settling time could easily be "violently" instantaneous'?

It is $\sim10^5$ years in the Earth's magnetic field, a fraction of a second near a permanent magnet. A small cm sized rare earth magnet can have magnetic field more than 1 Tesla, so one can easily create configurations with gradients $>10^{12}$ greater than the Earth's field gradient of only $\sim10$ pT/m.  The nominal settling time near the magnet is hence $>10^{24}$ times faster than in the Earth's field. $10^5 $ years  divided by $10^{24}$ is a few picoseconds, which which could certainly be considered "almost violently".

An ideal bismuth compass would eventually point along the lines of constant Earth magnetic field strength, which are typically roughly East-West, but:

Every measurement would take at least a hundred thousand years since that is minimum settling time needed for the needle to align itself East-West, and
The measurement would be ambiguous, since you wouldn't know which direction was East and which direction was West.

It would be much faster to just wait for a sunny day and determine East and West from where the Sun rises and sets, or to simply use a regular ferromagnetic compass.
Settling Time
Bismuth is strongly diamagnetic, so a small piece of bismuth with volume $V$ is repelled by a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ with a force:
$$
\vec{F}=\frac{\chi}{\mu_0}V\left(\vec{B} \cdot \vec{\nabla}\right)\vec{B}
$$
where $\chi=−1.66\times 10^{-4}$ is bismuth's volume magnetic susceptibility and $\mu_0$ is the permeability of vacuum. If the magnetic field and gradient are aligned (e.g. in the $z$ direction), this simplifies to:
$$
F=\frac{\chi}{\mu_0}V B \frac{\partial B}{\partial z}
$$
If my quick calculations are correct, for a needle with mass (per volume) density $\rho$, mass $M$, and length $L$, the torque around its midpoint will be
$$
\tau=\frac{\chi\,ML^2}{24\,\mu_0\,\rho}\,\left(\frac{\partial B}{\partial z}\right)^2\, \sin{2\theta}
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle of the needle with respect to the East-West direction.  For a thin needle whose radius is much less than its length, the angular acceleration due to this torque will be:
$$
\ddot{\theta}=\frac{\chi}{2\,\mu_0\,\rho}\,\left(\frac{\partial B}{\partial z}\right)^2\, \sin{2\theta}
$$
Near 45° North, the magnetic field strength is about $45\,\mathrm{\mu T}$, with a field gradient $\sim 20\,\mathrm{pT/m}$ in altitude and $\sim 5\,\mathrm{pT/m}$ in latitude.
This would give the bismuth needle an angular acceleration:
$$\ddot{\theta} \sim 3\times 10^{-25}\ \mathrm{radians/s^2}$$
So if the needle starts off randomly oriented at $\theta\sim 45$° to the East-West direction, it will take about
$$t_{settling} \sim \sqrt{2 \theta/\ddot{\theta}} \sim 100,000\ \mathrm{years}
$$
for the needle to align and settle in the East-West direction.
This is a rather long wait, and we haven't even considered that movements of the Earth's magnetic poles and seismic, atmospheric, thermal, human, and other possible disturbances would likely mean the needle would never settle.
Ambiguity
Although the needle might eventually align itself to the East-West direction, either end of the needle is equally likely to point East or West.  To distinguish East from West, you'd need more information such as where the Sun rises and sets.  But if you can see where the Sun rises and sets daily, you don't need a bismuth compass that takes thousands of years to settle.

A sunny day is not required to ascertain east from west. Even on a cloudy day, the sun's glow at sun rise  and direction of travel will give the location of east & west.

It seems your analysis has ignored friction?

Friction could certainly be an issue for any real attempt to build such a compass, but as noted in this answer's first sentence, I was considering an "ideal" compass. My point was that even such an ideal bismuth compass would be pretty useless, so I didn't bother considering non-ideal engineering practicalities such as friction.
